# Laravel 5.5 send email by gmail, configuration from the database

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I have a function to send emails and it usually works. Now I want to set configuration for gmail and I see error "expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\r\n
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError"

I have unlocked captcha and allow for less safe applications.
When I use .env configuration all works. But in my case, I try to set configuration from the database.

```
protected function makeEmail($config, $data){
  try{
    $account =  Settings::getEmailItem($config->account);
    Config::set('mail.driver','smtp');
    Config::set('mail.host',$account['host']);
    Config::set('mail.port',$account['port']);
    Config::set('mail.password',$account['password']);
    Config::set('mail.username',$account['username']);
    Config::set('mail.from.name',$account['from']);
    Config::set('mail.from.address',$account['username']);
    //Config::set('mail.encryption','tls');

    $app = App::getInstance();
    $app->singleton(TransportManager::class, function($app){
      return new TransportManager($app);
    });

    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($app['swift.transport']->driver());
    Mail::setSwiftMailer($mailer);

    $recipients =  collect(explode(',',$config->recipients))->map(function($recipient) use($data){
      $matches;
      if(preg_match('/^{{\$(.+)}}/',trim($recipient),$matches)){
        if(array_key_exists($matches[1],$data)){
          return $data[$matches[1]];
        }
      }else{
        return $recipient;
      }
    })->all();
    //dd(config('mail'));
    Mail::to($recipients)->send(new SendFreeEmail($config, $data));
  }catch(\Exception $e){
    dd($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e->getLine(), $e->getFile());
  }
```

When I display `config('mail')` there are my data from the database.

Bellow is an image from `dd(config('mail'))`

[image]

Thanks in advance for any hints.

**EDIT:** I solved this problem but it's weird. When I set as driver "sendemail" as driver it works.

Comment: Account password in db probably salted and hashed, nobody store raw passwords.

Comment: password in the database is encoded but in config variable is plain text. I display config.mail variable before send and there all access data are ok

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure your gmail account settings ?

You need to keep Allow less secure apps : ON .

Answer (score 0):

It seems your configurations are cached.
`php artisan config:clear` command should solve your issue.

Laravel Documentation says:

> If you execute the config:cache command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the .env file will not be loaded and all calls to the env function will return null.

Comment: Still not working. I updated my post and added result of `dd(config('mail'))`. It looks the same before send and when throw error.